# Mouse wheel jump to last slide before sliding

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel-2

I made a slider using owl-carousel and jquery-mousewheel, the carousel works well except that when i go bit fast on the mouse wheel, more than 1 by 1 increment, the slide jump to the last slide before starting slide in the direction i choose. Any idea what can be the problem?

```
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel.big');
    owl.owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    nav:false,
    dots: false,
    smartSpeed: 1500,
    margin:0,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            smartSpeed: 800
        },
        992:{
            items:1,
            smartSpeed: 1500
        }
    }
});

    owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
        if (e.deltaY>0) {
            owl.trigger('next.owl');
        } else {
            owl.trigger('prev.owl');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```